# How to pick elements of a matrix in increasing numerial value order for a loop operation

Tags: matrix

I have a 3X3 matrix and want to select its elements in order of their increasing numerical value for a loop operation. How can I do it.

For example if

```
x = {{1, 4, 6}, {2, 5, 8}, {11, 14, 16}},
```

I want a use script which can feed its elements in increasing numerical values (1, 2, 4, ...etc) in a "For" operation along with their i&j values. 
`For[Xmin, Xmax, X++, Print[X, i, j]]`  should be able to give

```
{1, 1, 1}
    {2, 2, 1}
    {4, 2, 1} 

----
etc.
```

I want to know what script I should use for "X" 
thanks

Comment: Why should it have to be a loop? `SortBy[Flatten[MapIndexed[List, {{1, 4, 6}, {2, 5, 8}, {11, 14, 16}}, {2}], 1], First]`

Comment: To get your desired output from @J.M.'s comment, replace `List` with `Flatten@*List`.

Comment: Re avoiding loops, see [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18396/11035), especially point (3).

Comment: My problem might not be making much sense as I posted only part of it. Actually I have two 3X3 (say A & B) matrices. I want to perform a loop operation on the system such that elements of matrix A in the order of increasing numerical values are compared with the corresponding element of B such that if for the element [i, j]
If A[i j] < B[i, j] -> next higher magnitude A[i, j] is selected
Or if
A[i j] > B[i, j], a parameter m is increased in its value by 1, which will be used to stimulate the next step. Hope it helps in understanding my problem. Thanks

Comment: Consider asking that as a different question, tho I suspect that this is an XY problem.

Comment: Ok, I can post the complete problem as a separate Q. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
m = {{1, 4, 6}, {2, 5, 8}, {11, 14, 16}}
Sort@Catenate@MapIndexed[List[#1, Sequence @@ #2] &, m, {2}]
```

**Edit:** following jjc's suggestion, you could alternatively

```
Sort@Catenate@MapIndexed[Flatten@*List, m, {2}]
```

It is shorter but I assume less efficient, since it creates and then flattens a list.

Answer (score 0):

```
x = {{1, 4, 6}, {2, 5, 8}, {11, 14, 16}};
SortBy[{x[[##]], Sequence@##} & @@@ 
  Tuples[Range /@ Dimensions[x]], First]
```

yields:

```
(* {{1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 1}, {4, 1, 2}, {5, 2, 2}, {6, 1, 3}, {8, 2, 
  3}, {11, 3, 1}, {14, 3, 2}, {16, 3, 3}}*)
```